# Can't send email through Django and Gmail

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error while trying to send mail through gmail on my sign up form:

```
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 
<https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs\n5.7.14 
7Iv4Nop2BfVsxIWEI1h5NxEG5QKSiQP2IRGqFYj-mB1tr4my5OBVeMzEbuG1hSttzGi2z\n5.7.14 
O6-2CSgs_9v57jLx6MkoOy8yKLcw5zgCYzPQ40opvla_U9TqolpkdWMi5c4jyT1_>\n5.7.14 Please log in 
via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 v8sm557096wrc.114 - gsmtp')
```

Here is my smtp settings

```
# smtp settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xbxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'dgesfgg'
```

Comment: please share your views

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32302040/14457833 I'll suggest not to use personal gmail account for email sending it's insecure and sometime it give error you can try third party services to send email like https://sendgrid.com/

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks Alot.